# PHP Codeigniter isn't working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, logout

I am creating a website with php codeigniter. When I log-in it creates a session and redirects to the home page. When I log out, it destroys the session. When I write the url of the home page it works fine. But if i click on the 'Go back one page button' on the browser, it goes back to the home page. Even though the home page is supposed to check whether I am logged in or not. My code is given below. I hope I am clear in explaining my dilemma. If not, then please ask. Thanks in advance.

```
public function signin()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email2', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');
    $query = "select password from user where email = '{$this->input->post('email2')}';";

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        if($this->doj_database->check_signin($query, $this->input->post('password2')))
        {
            $query = "select * from user where email = '{$this->input->post('email2')}';";
            $data['user'] = $this->doj_database->search_with_email($query);
            $newdata = array('logged_in' => TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            $url = "/DIRTY_ONLINE_JUDGE/goto_home/{$data['user']['user_id']}";
            redirect($url);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('wrong_login');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('wrong_login');
    }
}




public function goto_home($id)
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $data['user'] = $this->doj_database->search_with_id($id);
        $data['user']['password'] = $this->encrypt->decode($data['user']['password']);
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('not_logged_in');
    }
}



public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->load->view('index');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
    header('Expires: 0');
```

this in

```
public function goto_home($id)
{

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
    header('Expires: 0');
```

OR

```
        $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
        $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
     $data['user'] = $this->doj_database->search_with_id($id);
     $data['user']['password'] = $this->encrypt->decode($data['user']['password']);
     $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
    else
    {
      $this->load->view('not_logged_in');
    }
}
```

So that the page cache will be removed